# Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, cfnetwork

I'm getting the following crash report in Crashlytics:

```
Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader    
    SIGSEGV
    SEGV_ACCERR
    0 CoreFoundation    CFDictionaryGetValue + 27    
    1 CFNetwork XTubeManager::withTubeManager(CoreSchedulingSet const*, void (GlueTubeManager*) block_pointer) + 57    
    2 CFNetwork XTubeManager::withTubeManager(CoreSchedulingSet const*, void (GlueTubeManager*) block_pointer) + 57    
    3 CFNetwork -[__NSURLSessionLocal _withConnectionCache_enqueueRequest:forProtocol:scheduling:options:] + 125  
    4 CFNetwork HTTPProtocol::asynchronouslyCreateAndOpenStream_WithMessage_AfterCookiesAndAuthenticatorHeaders(__CFHTTPMessage*) + 1545    
    5 CFNetwork HTTPProtocol::asynchronouslyAddAuthenticatorHeadersAndContinue(__CFHTTPMessage*) + 101    
    6 CFNetwork invocation function for block in HTTPProtocol::asynchronouslyAddCookiesAndContinue(__CFHTTPMessage*) + 23  
    7 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_client_callout + 23     
    8 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_block_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 447    
    9 CFNetwork RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 19
    10 CoreFoundation   CFArrayApplyFunction + 36     
    11 CFNetwork    RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 183   
    12 CFNetwork    MultiplexerSource::perform() + 217    
    13 CFNetwork    MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 49    
    14 CoreFoundation   ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15   
    15 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 453    
    16 CoreFoundation   ___CFRunLoopRun + 795    
    17 CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520    
    18 CoreFoundation   CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108    
    19 CFNetwork    +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 487  
    20 Foundation   ___NSThread__start__ + 1149    
    21 libsystem_pthread.dylib  __pthread_body + 139   
    22 libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_start + 110
```

Comment: Are you using NSURLConnection?  NSURLSession?  Any custom NSURLProtocol subclasses?  Can you show us the code you're using to make requests?

Comment: I would recommend duping this to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448738/xtubemanager-crash-in-background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XTubeManager crash in background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448738/xtubemanager-crash-in-background)